# Why is the ListView's footer Showing up?

Tags: android, listview

I implemented a subclass of ListActivity and added this to OnCreate() method:

```
// Create a new MyAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());

// Put divider
getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

// Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
TextView footerView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view,
            null);

// Add footerView to ListView
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);

getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter)
```

But, the getView() method in MyAdapter does nothing:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout itemAdapter = null;
    return itemAdapter;
}
```

And I didn't add any item to the Adapter, I use this:

```
footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent AddItemIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,
        AddItemActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(AddItemIntent, ADD_ITEM_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

So the user can add items (like in a shopping list). But at the very beginning, there's no items the adapter should handle.

Comment: haw many items have you set for your adapter? where do you add them? I'm afraid that you are not populating your adapter. Please, post the whole code to make your problem easier!!

Comment: I edited my post. And yes, I'm not populating my adapter. But I only want to know why the footer is showing even though there is nothing in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listview headers and footers are not linked to how many items you have in your listview so even though your list is empty the footer will appear